# Help finding derivative using general gradient function - probably simple algebra mistake

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to brush up on my algebra and differentiation, I'm self-learning so I don't have a way to figure out this simple mistake I've made other than asking here, so sorry if this is a bit noob -

All my working out for calculating the derivative of $1/x$ using the general gradient function is below, the answer given in my textbook is circled at the bottom. As you can see I've got too many $\delta x$s in my denominator in my answer, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. I have a feeling it must be step 1 -> 2 - but why / how?

My textbook uses a slightly different approach to solve it, working out $f(x - \delta x) - f(x)$ first, simplifying that on it's own, THEN dividing by $\delta x$ - I guess that's a simpler (better?) approach but it means I can't follow through my workings with the textbook workings.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake happens in the last line.

$$\frac{-\delta x ^2}{x^2\cdot\delta x^2 - x\cdot\delta x^3}\neq \frac{-1}{x^2\cdot\delta x + x\cdot\delta x ^2}$$

You need to factor $\delta x$ out in the numerator to get

$$x^2\cdot\delta x^2 - x\cdot\delta x^3 =\delta x^2 (x^2-x\cdot\delta x)$$

Comment: {slaps head} d'oh! Thanks, that's so embarrasingly obvious now